# calculate average value of area around center pixel in python

Tags: python, filter, average, mask

I have a very large 2D array and want to filter out some small features. Therefore I would like to calculate the mean value of an area around a center pixel. If this value is below a certain threshold then set the value of the center pixel to zero in a mask. Are there ready-made python functions for this? For simplicity, let's say the input is a 5-by-9 array with integer entries and the average should be done over a 2-by-2 mask with threshold 7.

Comment: scipy and numpy http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html#scipy.signal.convolve2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code(threshold set to 7, average set to a 2-by-2 area):

```
Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 27 2015, 12:06:50) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy import signal
>>> a = np.array([[2,3,2,3,5,7,3,6,1],[2,3,2,7,3,1,3,6,2],[345,1345,45,2,6,1,0,1,1],[2,3,2,456,5,7,3,1,1],[2,789,2,8,5,7,3,6,1]])
>>> b = np.array([[0.25,0.25],[0.25,0.25]])
>>> c = signal.convolve2d(a,b,boundary='symm',mode='same')
>>> threshold = 7.
>>> a[c<np.ones([5,9])*threshold]=0
>>> a
array([[   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
   [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
   [ 345, 1345,   45,    2,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
   [   2,    3,    2,  456,    5,    0,    0,    0,    0],
   [   0,  789,    2,    8,    5,    0,    0,    0,    0]])
>>>
```